# Paint layers in texture paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

I have a skin texture that I'm trying to paint cuts and bruises on but, if I need to go back and retry a cut I can't erase it without also erasing the skin image I'm painting on. Is there a way I can paint on the image without also erasing the image when I need to repaint a detail>

Comment: Texture paint in Blender is quite limited. There are no layers yet. You can use programs like *Substance Painter* or *Armor Paint* for that

Comment: I completely forgot I had Armor Paint! Thank you

Comment: why don't you just use two or more image textures and use that as painting and then use color mix?

Comment: @Chris Thank you I was able to use that, here is a picture of what I did. https://imgur.com/a/7NiOp42